# WooCommerce Check if order is paid/processing or completed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to set a value "paid" in my custom table when the payment was successful / the customer gets redirectd to the thankyou page.

Im not sure if its secure enough to insert "paid => 1" just when the buyer reached the thankyou page. Thats why i wanted to check if the order was really paid, completed or processing.

Now i figured some payment methods are slow? When i checkout with Klarna my method works and it inserts paid = 1, but when I choose Paypal my Method will die and return: "WASNT PAID". But when I refresh the thankyou-page like 30 secs later it works. So i came to the conclusion that the order_status isnt set fast enough? Is there a cleaner way than mine?

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'ceb_order_complete', 10, 1);
function ceb_order_complete( $order_id ) {

    if ( ! $order_id )
        return;

    // Getting an instance of the order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if($order->is_paid() || $order->has_status('processing') || $order->has_status('completed')) {
        global $wpdb;
        $payID = WC()->session->get( 'payID' );
        if(!empty($payID)) {
            if(!$wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix."ceb_registrations", array("paid"=>1), array("payID"=>$payID))) {
                die("ERROR IN PAYMENT COMPLETE");
            }
        }
    } else {
        die("WASNT PAID");
    }
}
```

Comment: You will never get useful answers, if you ask things where people have to guess how your code works. When does 'payID' session variable is set, where is it come from?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have specified my question. payID is set when the user makes a booking in my custom plugin. (that works now by the way, i answered my last question for that). I figured some payment methods wont hook into "payment_complete" so i try to use the thankyou hook instead. It works fine, but  in some cases this method will die "WASNT PAID" even tho the customer was redirected after the payment. It happened with paypal. So my question is: Is there a way to check if the payment was successful on the thankyou page?

Comment: This can't be really answered because we can't test your code (or understand it)… So if you want real effective and useful answers and not opinion based answers, you need to ask different. Remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers."* StackOverFlow is a community and threads are for this community usage before individuals.

Comment: Allright, im still very new here. Im will think about my question and how to explain it properly and ask again tomorrow8after deleting this). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just using this now. But I will ask for sure. It happened accidently since I wasnt using this platform very much in the past.

Comment: Nice little icon… much better :) … Note that `if ( $order->is_paid() ) {` is exactly the same thing than `if ( $order->has_status('processing') || $order->has_status('completed') ) {`

Answer (score 3):

"woocommerce_thankyou" hook will run each time you see/refresh thankyou page.
The most suitable way is to process data after payment received. For that you can use "woocommerce_payment_complete".

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'payment_complete_callback');
function payment_complete_callback($order_id)
    {
      $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
      $user = $order->get_user();
      // do what ever you want to do using $order object of the WC_Order class providing many functions
    }
```